# What are the rules for territory ownership when you raze a city?

Tags: civilization-5

If I raze a conquered city its territory returns to neutral ownership. However suppose I have multiple cities clustered together, it is not always possible to know which tiles I will lose when razing a city.

Since I am a relatively peaceful player I have not had the chance to experiment with this game mechanic.

So what are the rules which dictate which tiles belong to a particular city when it is razed?

Comment: While I don't have an answer, be aware that in the past I have lost a tile of my own after conquering and then razing a city which was immediately next to that tile. So razing a  city seems to be able to remove tiles from you even if another city is actively working them.

Comment: I'd assume that borders are simply recalculated based on a city's accumulated culture and the usual rules that govern border growth. This may rejiggle borders a bit, since tile acquisition preference depends on a lot of factors AFAIK. This is all entirely my assumption though. :)

Comment: @Oak, this is very interresting. Are you sure that you were still working that tile in your original city and not in the razed one? I always thought that the tile ownership is declared by: 1. tile aquisition by culture or money 2. exchange of worked tiles between your cities.

Comment: @Adj no, I cannot be sure. All I know is that I chose the "raze" option immediately. But as cities take at least one turn to get destroyed, it's possible the "governor" AI allocated a citizen on that tile (even though the city was rioting, so not much point there).

Comment: @Oak The close-by city could have worked that tile, even if culturally it belonged to the city being razed. As long as a tile is within the 3 tile radius of a city and belongs to you, the city can work it.

Comment: Well, no exactly. If two cities overlap a tile they can both work it, but a tile still "belongs" just to one city, originally to the city which aquired it. That means that only in that (owner) city a governor can assign to work that tile or you can assign it by a single click. Notice that when assigning to work that tile in the other city you have to double click the tile, which then changes the ownership of the tile. So in Oak's case it must have been either some glitch or some game mechanics I don't know about.

Comment: @Adj So this is an interesting line, I'm wondering if it should get its own question or we should just make this one more generic.  What you say suggests that if a city is about to be captured, I should double-click on as many of its tiles from my other nearby cities to transfer ownership of them and thus reduce the territory that will be captured with my city.  Is that correct/possible?

Comment: @bwarner, that's pretty much what I fought about after writing this comment :). Or you could capture a nearby enemy city, aquire its tiles and then raze it. We have to check it.

Comment: @Adj I went ahead and created a new question for it, although I have a feeling that discovering the answer for it may also give us the answer to this question.

Comment: @Oak -- we've got copies of Civ V. We can play multiplayer games, let's test it!

Comment: @Raven man, don't tempt me... I'm on a self-imposed ban from playing videogames, RL issues :(

Comment: @Oak -- :( Hope they work out for you, those issues!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So based on [Fabian's answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10690/does-working-a-tile-with-a-city-transfer-ownership-of-the-tile-to-that-city) combined with Oak's experience mentioned in the comments for this question, it sounds like razing a city will cause all tiles that were acquired by that city to become neutral, as well as all tiles in the immediate ring around that city, even if those tiles were not initially acquired by the city being razed (beacuse as Fabian pointed out, building/capturing a city will automatically transfer ownership of tiles in that inner ring that belong to other cities of the same player to the "new" city).  Any tiles in the inner ring that do not belong to the player owning the city should not become neutral.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any way to determine ahead of time which city initially acquired a tile and thus "owns" it for purposes such as this.

Comment: There is an exception to this when claiming land using a Great General's Citidel. Any land claimed and added to one of your neighbouring cities, in the inner ring of a city you conquer and then raze will also become neutral.